# How to make a fixed position for two header and content to be scroll-able

Tags: html, css

> I've created a two headers with the title ,and how to do content  scroll-able the issue is that the content shifts over on the header, how to make responsive for all screens can any help me out of this,
>   How can I get fixed two headers, with scrollable content?Here is the HTML and CSS I have set up for this

```css
/* relevant styles */
.panel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
    
    display: -moz-flex;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    
    display: -ms-flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

header {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width:100em;
}
.body{
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 2em;
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 1em;
}
footer{
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* helper styles */
body{
    font: 13px serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.control {
    position: absolute;
    left: 360px;
    top: 30px;
}
label{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div><header>channel</header></div>
<div class="panel">
    <header><h1>Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ev</h1></header>
    <div class="body">
        <p>Body text</p>
<div>
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

﻿Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
</div>
    </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: you should add .header{position:fixed;}

Comment: I want to change div format?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS & HTML Like

```css
/* relevant styles */
*{
box-sizing: border-box;}
body,html,.wrapper{
height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;}
header {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1em;
    width:100vw;
}
.body{
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 1em;
}
footer{
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* helper styles */
body{
    font: 13px serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.control {
    position: absolute;
    left: 360px;
    top: 30px;
}
label{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper><header>channel</header>
<div class="panel">
    <header><h1>Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ev</h1></header>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p>Body text</p>
<div>
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”



Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”

Sometime we can feel a bit dull in the morning and we need to produce our own sunshine energy.

Other times we come downstairs feeling sunny already. Those are great days!

Whether you’re feeling a little blue, or you’re fired up ready to have the best day ever…

Either way, I think we can all do with a bit more spark to help us perform miracles and live in joy.

So here are 17 wonderful, short positive quotes has collected for you . sdfsdf dsfs dfg yuj hjtytwe ggf

They will brighten up ANY day, so much that you’ll be having to wear sunglasses all the time 

We also have a powerful and proven Law of Attraction gift which you can access by clicking the link below…

“Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace”
</div>
    </div>
   
</div>
```